# Extracting certain Powerpoint slides based on an Excel table and combine to new presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a huge PPT presenation (>400 slides) and want to extract certain pages based on an Excel table and create a new, smaller presentation. 
I created an Excel table which includes the page numbers as well as the title of each slide in the PPT presentation.

The goal now is, to have a macro that allows me to create a new PPT with all the slides that are mentioned in my (sorted) Excel table.

As I am new with VBA (I am only able to copy/paste code and run it afterwards), I was not able to try anything.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've done similar and found it much easier to _delete_ the unneeded slides from a copy of the template of all slides, then `.SaveAs` than it was to copy them into a new, blank PPT. Without care, you end up losing a lot of formatting, especially if you're using any sort of custom template in the slides. I'm sure it's possible to retain it, but I found it easier to go the other way.

Comment: Thanks! That would also work for me. Do you have code that you can perhaps share from your similar efforts?